# vuedraggable handle attribute not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable

I'm trying to use vuedraggable inside a table, but I am unable to rearrange the table rows with my desired handle:

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpp3xry63

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <RowComponent/>
    <Draggable
        v-model="data"
        v-bind="drag_options"
        handle="[name=dragger]"
        tag="table"
        @start="drag = true"
        @end="drag = false"
    >
        <thead slot="header">
            <th>
                Placeholder
            </th>
            <th>
                Map Level
            </th>
            <th>
                Revision
            </th>                    
        </thead>
        <transition-group
            type="transition"
            :name="!drag ? 'flip-list' : null"
            tag="tbody"
        >
            <row-component
                v-for="row in data"
                :key="row._id"
            />
        </transition-group>
    </Draggable>        
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Draggable from "vuedraggable"
import RowComponent from "./components/Row.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Draggable,
    RowComponent
  },
  data ()
  {
    return {
      data:
      [
          {
              _id:
              1,
          },
          {
              _id:
              2,
          },
          {
              _id:
            3,
          },
      ],
      drag:
          false,                
      drag_options: 
      {
          animation: 
              200,
          group: 
              "description",
          disabled: 
              false,
          ghostClass: 
              "ghost"
      },
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    table
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    table, th, td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Row.vue

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div name="draggable">Move</div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-color-primary btn-size-normal">Rename</button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-color-primary btn-size-normal"
            @click="showing.note = !showing.note"
          >Note</button>
          <button class="btn btn-color-orange btn-size-normal">Draw</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea v-if="showing.note"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showing: {
        note: false
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

textarea {
  font-size: initial;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

[name="draggable"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the github doc

> Limitation: neither header or footer slot works in conjunction with transition-group.

If you remove header slot and handle it works fine. [updated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oo2z3mq789)

Comment: well the whole point of using a table is to be able to use the table header, maybe I'll try it without transition group then.

Comment: you can put the header above the v-for tho. otherwise you have to adjust the code to work with current lib behaviour

Comment: I don't understand, I removed the `slot` and it still didn't work. Maybe make an update to what you mean?